# editable element placeholder not smooth

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a contentEditable element,and I add a placeholder for it by javascript, but it has 200ms delay,here is the code

javascript:

```
function handlePlaceholder () {
    var $input = $('.input');
    var $placeholder = $('.placeholder');
    if ($input.html()) {
        $placeholder.hide();
    } else {
        $placeholder.show();
    }
}

$('.input').on('focus blur keyup', function() {
    handlePlaceholder();
})
```

html:

```
<div class="placeholder">input here</div>
<div class="input" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

css:

```
.input {
    width: 200px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.placeholder {
    color: #cdcdcd;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

when the keyup event trigger the handlePlaceholder function, it has 200ms delay, but the real html placeholder dose not.

**My question: is there another way to add placeholder for contentEditable element,or how to do it in this way without the delay?**

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zhouxiaoping/pkgzrb7w/3/

200ms is not the excatly time ,just description

Comment: why won't you just use normal `input` element with `placeholder` attribute http://jsfiddle.net/pkgzrb7w/4/ ?

Comment: it must be a contenteditable-element,because it will contain not just text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `keydown` event with `setTimeout` on zero timeout to trigger the function immediately after default event handler (so the input value will be updated at the time)

```
$('.input').on('focus blur keydown', function() {
    setTimeout(handlePlaceholder, 0);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pkgzrb7w/6/

Comment: thank you for your help,it works, you are so smart,just call the function after keydown

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are handling "keyup" event. Try to use keydown instead.

Comment: when the keydown event triggered, the value of the input has not been changed